# Let $X,Y\not=\emptyset$ and $\phi : X\mapsto Y$ an injective function. Find a function $\Phi: 2^X\mapsto 2^Y$ injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X,Y\not=\emptyset$ and $\phi : X\mapsto Y$ an injective function. Find a function $\Phi: 2^X\mapsto 2^Y$ injective

I'm lost in this proof. I know that if $\phi$ is injective then $|X|\leq |Y|$, so that we can give the $\Phi$ injective function. But I don't see how to build that function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $\Phi: 2^X\to 2^Y$ by $\Phi(A)=\phi(A)$, i.e it is the image of the set $A$ under the map $\phi$. We have to show $\Phi$ is injective. So assume $\Phi(A)=\Phi(B)$. This means $\phi(A)=\phi(B)$. We will show that this implies $A=B$.

Let $x\in A$. Then $\phi(x)\in\phi(A)=\phi(B)$. By the definition of $\phi(B)$ it follows that there is some $y\in B$ such that $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$. But $\phi$ is injective, and so $x=y$. Hence $x\in B$. So this shows that $A\subseteq B$, and similarly you can show the reverse inclusion.

Comment: Or use that $\phi$ injective iff $\phi^{-1}[\phi[A]] = A$ for all $A \subseteq X$.